# DocuSign Customize Email in Brand To Use [[EnvelopeId]] in a link

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to customize the brand resource file so that it uses the EnvelopeId within a query parameter in a custom html link so that the destination site can filter rows based on the Envelope.

For example, when using the following in the DocuSign XML Email resources file for the brand (e.g. in envelope completed email):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=[[EnvelopeId]]" target="_blank">View Rows</a>
```

DocuSign escapes the [[EnvelopeId]] (presumably because its within a link), causing the resulting html for the email to be

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=[[EnvelopeId]]" target="_blank">View Rows</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=62cbb3b9-e09a-4c8d-af88-99e9ef871113">View Rows</a>
```

Is there a way to prevent the EnvelopeId from being escaped or another way to use the EnvelopeId with a custom link in the envelope completion email?

Comment: Are you attempting to do this through the API?

Comment: No, on the website I am customizing the DocuSign Email Resources XML File within a Brand. 
Preferences=>Branding=>Edit=>Resources
(https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER/MemberAccountBranding.aspx)

Comment: Please direct your question to http://community.docusign.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see [[ ]] that refers to something called a DocuSign Merge Field. As you are referring to, these are dynamic variables which get replaced with expected values at runtime. I do not believe that EnvelopeID is a valid merge field in this context. The closest thing you have to referencing a link to the envelope is the [[QuickURL]] merge field.

If you were going down an API integrated route, you could specify the entire email message body contents via the API, and you would know the envelopeID at that point and could pass it in w/your logic.